# VB.NET 2010 database search

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, search

I have a ms access database connected to my vb application through the data wizard.
i want to allow the user to search the database and display their results on a datagrid.
for example user searches for 50 – 55 year Old man under 1.8 meters in height

so far i can display the total amount of people on the database with this code

```
    Private Sub lblTotalPeople_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblTotalPeople.Click
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\AssignmentDatabase.accdb")
    ' Use wildcard'
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select COUNT(*) From Table1", con)
    '' or Where username='" & TextBox1.Text & "'
    con.Open()
    Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
    myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "Table1")
    DataGridView2.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("Table1").DefaultView

End Sub
```

how would i search the database based on what the user searches or what would i use?

Comment: There's afew ways you can attack this, but seeing as it's MS Access, have a look through this lot. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ay5y4w0(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't already you need to learn how to use SQL.

In your code above the SQL statement is

`Select COUNT(*) From Table1`

You would need to replace this SQL with a search that uses a value from the user (most likely from a textbox). This text

`'' or Where username='" & TextBox1.Text & "'`

appears to be part way to some SQL that may work but it looks dangerous. You should also research SQL Injection as using this directly means users could access/damage your Access database.

Comment: I have done it using this:   Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from Table1 where Age  Between '" & txtAge1.Text & "' AND '" & txtAge2.Text & "'", con) and it works. Thank you

Comment: Your welcome, be careful though because if someone adds something dangerous into the textboxes then they could delete all your data - you need to check for dangerous characters like other apostrophes, search for SQL Injection.